# Batch Script to check Windows 7 Activation

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to do a batch script to check the Activation status of the workstations of my LAN, so far I have the following code that saves into a .txt the status of the activation.

```
@echo off
cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr > ActivatedStatus.txt | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1
if [%errorlevel%]==[0] (echo Not permanently activated.) else (echo Permanently activated)
exit /b
```

An the output ActivatedStatus.txt looks like this:

```
Windows(R) 7, Professional edition:
The machine is permanently activated.
```

What I want is to just create a .txt if the workstation is not activated but I can't get to work the if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By both attempting to both redirect and pipe on the same command line, you're only redirecting, nothing is being feed into `findstr`.  So, you'll either need to only pipe the data along:

```
cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1
```

Or, if you want to create the text file, you need to create it first, then pipe it's data to `findstr`:

```
cscript /nologo c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /xpr > ActivatedStatus.txt
type ActivatedStatus.txt | findstr /i /c:" will expire "> NUL 2>&1
```

Comment: The last line is a Windows variation of [useless use of cat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat). You could just redirect the stdin of `findstr` to the file using `<`.

Comment: Sure, but unlike Unix, the purpose of type is to type a file, not combine files (though it can do that), and there's no waste of a process since type is built into the command processor.  Also, it looks cleaner to me to explain the actions to a new user.  Either way works, though.